# three.js - how do I get the vertices of an object?

Tags: three.js, blender, collada, vertices

I am trying to import a model from blender and loop through all vertices. I am using the colladaloader for the import. It all works fine and the model is loading. But I do not want the faces of the model - I only need the vertex positions for my purposes.

Can anyone tell me if there is a way to do this? e.g. a loop that loops through all vertices of the imported model?

Thanks,
Tomo

Answer (score 5):

Now it is:

```
       var vertices = mesh.geometry.attributes.position.array;
      

        for (let i = 0; i < vertices.length; i=i+3) {
            //a vertex' position is (vertices[i],vertices[i+1],vertices[i+2])
        }
```

Comment: How can I move a vertice at a certain position?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you import your Blender Model as a mesh, using a loader module. The mesh has a geometry it is based on. And the geometry has a vertices-Array. Just iterate over that? And maybe just don't add it to the scene if you don't want to display the model?
At first glance, your question seems not very well researched. Check out the Mesh object structure and see the Three.js Examples!

Answer (score 1):

If `geo` represents your geometry:

```
for (var i = 0; i < geo.vertices.length; i++)
{
    var v = geo.vertices[i];
    // do stuff with v...

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok now I got it...

console.log() helped me a lot to see what structure is behind the loaded .dae file.

```
loader.load( './models/collada/test.dae', function ( collada ) {                
    for(i = 0; i < collada.scene.children.length; i++) {
        if(collada.scene.children[i].geometry) {
            for(j = 0; j < collada.scene.children[i].geometry.vertices.length; j++) {
                //do stuff...
            }
        }
    }

    //...
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

I create function which traverse vertices in whole object (all childrens) and you can pass callback to do something with each vertices. It handle all possible object variations and mesh types.

In implementation I using array as stack (no recursion here).

```
private static traverseObjectVertices(obj: Object3D, callback: (v: Vector3) => void): void {
const front = Array<Object3D>();
if (Array.isArray(obj)) {
  for (let i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
    front.push(obj[i]);
  }
} else {
  front.push(obj);
}
while (front.length > 0) {
  // pop have better performance than shif, and we can go from back in this case
  const obj = front.pop();
  if (obj) {
    if (obj instanceof Mesh && obj.geometry !== undefined) {
      const vertices = obj.geometry.vertices;
      const vertex = new Vector3();
      if (vertices === undefined && obj.geometry.attributes !== undefined && "position" in obj.geometry.attributes) {
        const pos = obj.geometry.attributes.position;
        for (let i = 0; i < pos.count * pos.itemSize; i += pos.itemSize) {
          vertex.set(pos.array[i], pos.array[i + 1], pos.array[i + 2]);
          callback(vertex.applyMatrix4(obj.matrixWorld));
        }
      } else {
        for (let i = 0; i < vertices.length; ++i) {
          callback(vertex.copy(vertices[i]).applyMatrix4(obj.matrixWorld));
        }
      }
    }
    if (obj.children !== undefined) {
      for (const child of obj.children) {
        front.push(child);
      }
    }
  }
}
}
```