# Getting top left corner vertex position in threejs

Tags: three.js

I'm importing a model from Blender that looks like this:

[image]

If I wanted to get the top left vertex position of say this part:

[image]

how would I go about doing this?

I've looked at other questions like this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18967423/three-js-how-do-i-get-the-vertices-of-an-object) but none of the geometries on my meshes have a vertices array - do I need to go through `Object.3D` to find it?

Also - I'm trying to create an outline for each of the meshes - an example of what this should look like would be this(forgive the terrible attempt at an outline - GIMP is not my strong point):

[image]

Comment: **1)** Please pplit your outline question into a separate question. It'll help keep SO organized. **2)** It depends on what you mean by "top left." Is it the top-left-most of camera space? Or screen space? Or do you have a concept of top/left in world space? How does depth play into this?

Comment: I mean in terms positions assigned to the mesh.

Comment: `JSONLoader` creates `Geometry` objects, so it's surprising that you aren't seeing arrays of vertices. Are you performing any intermediate steps, like converting the `Geometry` objects to `BufferGeometry`?